# Is there a way to edit unassigned materials in the shader editor?

Tags: materials, shaders

I have a material, that is not assigned to any object. I use it as a material override in a pass (View Layer) only.

Do someone knows a way to edit (see) materials in the shader editor, that are not assigned to any object?

Thank you

Comment: You mean not assigned but linked or neither assigned nor linked? Having material linked but not assigned is a way to go with overrides.

Comment: Hello :). There's no way to edit unassigned material. Why not just add a new object to use for preview, and disable it in render and viewport?

Comment: The workarond, that I've finally used is to create a dummy object, which is always invisible (even in render) and use it as a material container. I hope there will be a better solution in the future. Thank you!